# image not storing Media folder

Tags: magento-1.9, media

I uploaded image file name called `!!!.png` it stored in Database but in Media it stored file.png i don't know what is the problem

```
public function fanbookAction(){
        $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
                if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) 
                {
                    try{
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
                        $destFile = $path.'/'.str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['img']['name']);
                        $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $uploader->save($path, $filename);
                        $img ='FanBook/'.$filename;
                        $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
                        $collection ->setData('img',$img);
                        $collection->save();

                        $this->_redirectReferer();
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Request has been Completed Successfully');
                    }

                    catch(Exception $e) {

                         $this->_redirectReferer();
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Upload Error');

                    }


                }
    }
```

**Updated**

```
try{
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
                        $destFile = $path.'/'.str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['img']['name']);
                        //$filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $fileName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-\\.]+/i', '_', $fileName);
                        if (preg_match('/^_+$/', $fileInfo['filename'])) {
    $fileName = 'file.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
}

                        $uploader->save($path, $filename);
                        $img ='FanBook/'.$filename;
                        $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
                        $collection ->setData('img',$img);
                        $collection->save();

                        $this->_redirectReferer();
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Request has been Completed Successfully');
                    }
```

Comment: change line `$uploader->save($path, $filename)` to `if(!$uploader->save($path, $filename) )){
     throw new Exception($this->__('There might be a problem with  directory permission.'));
     }` check it will throw exception.

Comment: After adding this it shows blank page

Answer (score 1):

Problem is **you cannot have an uploaded file called `!!!.png`**.

When your code runs, the `save()` method of `Varien_File_Uploader` is called and it will sanitize the file name using `$fileName = self::getCorrectFileName($fileName)`

This method uses a regular expression to get rid of the unwanted characters such as the exclamation mark:

```
static public function getCorrectFileName($fileName)
{
    $fileName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-\\.]+/i', '_', $fileName);
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($fileName);

    if (preg_match('/^_+$/', $fileInfo['filename'])) {
        $fileName = 'file.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
    }
    return $fileName;
}
```

Step by step:

```
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-\\.]+/i', '_', $fileName);
```

The `$fileName` will be `_.png` after this line.

Then:

```
if (preg_match('/^_+$/', $fileInfo['filename'])) {
    $fileName = 'file.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
}
```

The `$fileName` will be `file.png` after this line.

**To fix your problem you need to change your file name to something valid.**

Comment: Where i need to add this in my controller or what

Comment: @Kothari see my update

Comment: Still i am not getting can you please update the answer

Comment: @Kothari what are you not getting ?

Comment: in which file i need to add this static public function getCorrectFileName($fileName)

Comment: @Kothari you don't need to add that function, that function is already in Varien_File_Uploader and that's the function that renames your file automatically. You need to change your file name, `!!!.png` is not a valid filename and Magento will always change it

Comment: Check my updated question that is correct or not

Comment: @Kothari no your original code was good, don't change it with the function I pasted. Just change your file name from `!!!.png` to something else.

Comment: How to change it